# How can I map a domain to Milvus Vector Database?

Tags: milvus

I'm trying to install Milvus vector database on a server and set a domain name to it (using traefik preferably). So far no success: I cannot connect to that Milvus domain from Python script (when run locally: the connection works).

What is your experience with setting up Milvus behind a domain? Thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You should show some code or configuration in your question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Please also take the [tour]. Further, a [mcve] is always helpful, because your vague "doesn't work" is useless without hard facts like what you did.

Comment: What way did you install milvus?